# I can't run my "a.exe", made with mingw whenever I have a class constructor and destructor, c++?

Tags: c++, class, cmd, mingw, header-files

I am relatively new to C++, I just finished the online course available on `codecademy.com`. So I decided to download MinGW and VScode to start doing some practice. Everything was going fine until I ran into an error that I can't fix.

This Error appears when I try to run my executable:

[image]

I am typing this into `cmd`, no makefile used:

```
D:\>g++ main.cpp app.cpp
D:\>a.exe
```

I am using mingw (g++) in the command line to compile my code, which is here:

my main.cpp file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "app.hpp"
    int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

        App tomato(true);
        std::cout << tomato.get_sauce();
        tomato.~App();
        return 0;
    }
```

app.hpp:

```
// Define prototype functions here:
#ifndef APP_HPP
#define APP_HPP

class App {

    public:

    bool sauce;

    App(bool set);
    ~App();

    void set_sauce (bool set);
    bool get_sauce ();
};

#endif
```

app.cpp:

```
#include "app.hpp"
#include <iostream>

App::App (bool set) {
    sauce = set;
}

App::~App () {
    std::cout << "goodbye";
}

void App::set_sauce (bool set) {
    sauce = set;
}

bool App::get_sauce () {
    return sauce;
}
```

Everything compiles fine but as soon as I run the executable I get `The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library`.

Comment: This is not a C++ issue, it sounds like your installation is somehow damaged.

Comment: Sounds like the path didn't get set up right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy  `libstdc++-6.dll` from `mingw` folder into the the directory of your executable. Alternatively you can add the path to `libstdc++-6.dll` to the environment PATH.

Comment: Surely this is not the correct way to solve this issue. Copying the .dll file should not be needed. Is it really? Is this the way `mingw` works?

Comment: @lit I think the OP has multiple versions, and that is quickest solution. The better way is to add to the environment PATH.